# Firebase Function with Firebase Hosting redirects to wrong URL

Tags: javascript, firebase, cookies, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have a custom subdomain connected to Firebase Hosting - api.example.com

Additionally I have a function in Firebase Functions

```
exports.test = functions
    .region('europe-west3')
    .https.onRequest((request, response) => {
        const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 * 1000;
        const origin = request.headers.origin;

        const options = { maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: true, secure: true, sameSite: 'strict',  };
        response.cookie('__session', "123456", options);
        response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
        response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
        response.end(JSON.stringify({ status: 'success' }));
})
```

my Firebase.json looks like the following

```
{
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [{
        "source": "/test",
        "function": "test"
    }]
  }
}
```

Now when I'm trying to make a POST request to `https://api.example.com/test`
I get a error

> Your client does not have permission to get URL /test/test from this server.

which makes sense as the URL says `/test/test/`

What am I doing wrong here? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Hosting does not support regions other than us-central1 for Cloud Functions.  See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions):

> Important: Firebase Hosting supports Cloud Functions in us-central1 only.

See also this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/842